# JQuery Tabbing Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some html and JQuery that is used to create a page with tabbed content.  The html is below:

```
<section id="content" class="content">
    <ul class="tabs group">
         <li><a href="#">Tab 1</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Tab 2</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Tab 3</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="panes">
         <div class="group">
              tab1
         </div>         
         <div class="group">
              tab2
         </div>         
         <div class="group">
              tab3
         </div>   
    </div>
</section>
```

The JQuery is here:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {        
            $('.activetab a').each(function () {
                var activeTab = $(this).parents('li').index();
                var paneVisible = $(this).parents('ul').next().children('div').eq(activeTab);
                paneVisible.show().siblings().hide();
            });

            $('.tabs a').click(function () {           
                $(this).parents('li').addClass('activetab').siblings().removeClass('activetab'); var activeTab = $(this).parent('li').index();
                var paneVisible = $(this).parents('ul').next().children('div').eq(activeTab);
                paneVisible.show().siblings().hide();
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
```

This code works in the sense that when I click on one of the links the data in the correct tab appears.

The only problem is that when I go to the page (containing these tabs) for the first time I get the data from all the tabs displayed to me.  I need some extra code in my document ready function to display the data from the first tab and hide all the other data (and of course to highlight the first tab as well).  Any ideas how I may do this.  I am no JQuery/JavaScript expert.

Thanks,

Sachin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the `activetab` class to one of the `<li>` elements inside the `ul.tabs`, like this:

```
<li class="activetab"><a href="#">Tab 1</a></li>
```

You can see it here in action: http://jsfiddle.net/CAAFZ/

Answer (score 0):

Well, if there is not any specific reason, you can use JQuery UI's tab and achieve this functionality.

Check it out at:
http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/

Other way to do it is, in CSS add:

```
.tabs {display:none;}
```

And in your document.ready function add

```
$('.tabs').show();
```

This way, until the styling is good, the ugly display is not visible to the end user.

Missed Wrock's reply. That shall work too :)